# URL Query String without Question Mark?

Tags: url, query-string

I cannot find documentation anywhere regarding whether the following URL that has a query string is valid.

`http://www.example.com/webapp&someKey=someValue`

I know that `?` starts a list of key-value pairs separated by `&`.

Is the `?` required?

Answer (score 1):

`?` appears to be required for the trailing part to be called query.

Query string is defined in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). Section 3.3 Path says:

> The path component contains data, usually organized in hierarchical
> form, that, along with data in the non-hierarchical query component
> (Section 3.4), serves to identify a resource within the scope of the
> URI's scheme and naming authority (if any).  The path is terminated
> by the first question mark ("?") or number sign ("#") character, or
> by the end of the URI.

Section 3.4 defines query:

> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with
> data in the path component (Section 3.3), serves to identify a
> resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority
> (if any).  The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
> or by the end of the URI.

[RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) for URL has a section for HTTP URL scheme. It says in section 3.3 that:

> An HTTP URL takes the form:

```
  http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>
```

> where  and  are as described in Section 3.1. If :
> is omitted, the port defaults to 80.  No user name or password is
> allowed.   is an HTTP selector, and  is a query
> string. The  is optional, as is the  and its
> preceding "?". If neither  nor  is present, the "/"
> may also be omitted.

> Within the  and  components, "/", ";", "?" are
> reserved.  The "/" character may be used within HTTP to designate a
> hierarchical structure.

You can use tricks to take the URI as you mention and then split it as if it was a query string. Frameworks like Laravel, Django etc. allow you to handle routes in a query string like manner. There's more to it than what I say; I was just giving an example about Frameworks' handling of URIs.

Look at this example from Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#required-parameters. It shows how Laravel takes a route like https://site/posts/1/comments/3 and handles the post id 1 and comment id 3 through a function.

```
Route::get('posts/{post}/comments/{comment}', function ($postId, $commentId) {
    //
});
```

You can, perhaps, handle routes like http://site/webapp/somekey/somevalue.